# How to replace so many if else condition, apart from Switch statement and Polymorphism

Tags: java, coding-style

Similar to Tax system, I have to write the code where some discount range is given and It is very much possible that in future  I will get 10-20 more discount range.

**Actual Problem statement:** Shopping Cart

There are multiple types of customer(Regular, Premium) they have been given a discount based on their purchase amount. for e.x

**Premium Customer**

1. 0-$5000 0%
2. $5000-$10000 10%
3. 10000 - above 20%

**Regular Customer**

1. 0-$4000 10%
2. $4000 - $8000 15%
3. $8000 - $12000 20%
4. $12000 - above 25%

I tried if-else and switch statement but situation is same. every time I have to touch the already tested method and add either switch-case condition or else-if part or say 10 more classes if polymorphism.

What is the best way to tackle such situation where there are so many condition exists and can be added in future without touching previously written code

```
public class PremiumCustomerBillingStrategy extends BillingStrategy {

    @Override
    public double calculateFinalBill(double actualBillAmt) {

        double finalBillAmt;

        if (actualBillAmt <= 4000) {
            finalBillAmt = actualBillAmt - getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
        } else if (actualBillAmt > 4000 && actualBillAmt <= 8000) {
            finalBillAmt = actualBillAmt - getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
        } else if (actualBillAmt > 8000 && actualBillAmt <= 12000) {
            finalBillAmt = actualBillAmt - getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 8000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
        } else {
            finalBillAmt = actualBillAmt - getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 12000, PremiumDiscountEnum.ABOVE_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                    - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
        }
        return finalBillAmt;

    }
```

Comment: Just to be more specific, here I am looking out how to avoid so many if else statements. In this case currently there are just 3 condition but what if I get say 15 more such conditions in future. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a bit of an overkill in this case, but if the conditions get really numerous, you could use a class that expresses a function to apply on the amount, if it is within a desired range, like this:

```
public class Bills {

class BillFor {
    public final double rangeFrom;
    public final double rangeTo;
    public final Function<Double, Double> calculation;

    BillFor(double rangeFrom, double rangeTo, Function<Double, Double> calculation) {
        this.rangeFrom = rangeFrom;
        this.rangeTo = rangeTo;
        this.calculation = calculation;
    }
}

private final static float MIN = 0f;
private final static float MAX = Long.MAX_VALUE;

private List<BillFor> billings = List.of(new BillFor(MIN, 4000, i -> i - getDiscountedAmount(i, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount)),
                /*etc*/
                new BillFor(12000f, MAX, i -> i - 0 /* big expression actually*/));


public double calculateFinalBill(double actualBillAmt) {
    return billings.stream()
            .filter(b -> actualBillAmt > b.rangeFrom  && b.rangeTo <= actualBillAmt)
            .findAny()
            .map(b -> b.calculation.apply(actualBillAmt))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!, that seems to be a great solution. I will try it on my system first and then, will comment or accept it.

Comment: I think, I got the minRange-test wrong, it should be `actualBillAmt > b.rangeFrom`

Comment: Thanks, That was a perfect solution, I could implement the logic with suggested solution by you and I could not get a better suggestion/solution than this. I am not able to upvote due to less reputation but accepted the solution. It's really a creative way of solving such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are saying you don't write some code and you introduce new functionality which is neither a good practice nor possible. So, think of the case your test still passes or coverage is not reduced after you add a bunch of lines.

But that's a real problem. Hence,You can look up for following issues:

1. repeating calculations can be moved out of conditions. In this case move out getting final Bill amount calculation i.e. finalBillamount = actualBillAmt - discount should be outside all conditions above.
2. calculation of discount is could be abstraction to your code conditions here. Hence modularize this code and move to another method which calculates the discount for you. This way you would never be modifying anything in this set of code.

e.g. :

```
@Override
public double calculateFinalBill(double actualBillAmt) {
    return actualBillAmt- calculateDiscount(finalBillAmt );
}

public double calculateDiscount(double actualBillAmt) {
    double discount;

    if (actualBillAmt <= 4000) {
        discount = getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
    } else if (actualBillAmt > 4000 && actualBillAmt <= 8000) {
        discount= getDiscountAmountUpto8K(actualBillAmt );
    } else if (actualBillAmt > 8000 && actualBillAmt <= 12000) {
        discount= getDiscountAmountUpto12K(actualBillAmt );
    } else {
        discount = getDiscountAbove16k(actualBillAmt);
    }
    return discount;
}

public getDiscountAmountUpto8K(double actualBillAmt ){
return getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000,PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
}

public getDiscountAmountUpto12K(double actualBillAmt ){

return getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 8000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
}

public getDiscountAbove16k(double actualBillAmt ){
return getDiscountedAmount(actualBillAmt - 12000, PremiumDiscountEnum.ABOVE_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_TWELVE_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_EIGHT_THOUSAND.discount)
                - getDiscountedAmount(4000, PremiumDiscountEnum.BELOW_FOUR_THOUSAND.discount);
}
```

Now you can observe that discount calculation has been moved out of the original method. Hence, you will never need to modify test cases for that method. But that doesn't mean you won't be writing test cases for new conditions or any new methods added.

Comment: Now that is clean code. Agree. Problem statement is "In future there could be 50 new discount range". Now you have to keep adding if-else if... 50 more times. That I don't think so a good way to tackle. I am asking the other possibilities apart from Switch case

Comment: so, if you got possibilities like that you can only modularize because we don't know what those 50 conditions would be. You can use predicate to distinguish your conditions but still there is no way out to avoid  conditions in java normally.